# Movable objects in webpage

Tags: java, web-applications, metadata

say I have a site of tables and graphs, I want to be able to move those items around (drag and drop) and save the end positions in some sort of metadata format, so next time that user comes onto the page the same page format and tables pop up. I have an idea of how I'm going to format the backend tables, but don't really have a good idea of how to actually code it out. Any ideas? Preferably in java/jsp

Comment: Suggestions on the best way to set up the structure of these elements so that they could be flexable/scalable would also be appreciated. I was thinking of just having some struct where the type of item is a variable inside of the struct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out jquery / jquery-ui. You won't be able to do this in java/jsp alone.

In particular, check out these demos.

jqueryui.com/demos/draggable and jqueryui.com/demos/droppable

Comment: I've looked at jquery sortable, which allows up/down movement, but I'm looking for multiple element types and movable in any direction.